# GestureRecognizer is not working inside the ItemsControl in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, gesture-recognition

I am doing my current application in XAML/C# Windows Store apps, i load the bulk of Items in to the ListView to maintain the Virtualization in the page. I use the GestureRecognizer to obtain the Transition and Zooming of my control. My all these UIElements are inside the DataTemplate of my ListView. GestureRecognizer working fine without ListViewer.

But when ItemsControls comes into the picture, it stopped working and does not do any Transform in the page. Is there any workaround of this problem ?. I could guess some of the guys also facing this problem.

Could you please anyone help me on this ?